# Preparing hillshade map in mapinfo discover

Tags: mapinfo, hillshade, mapinfo-discover

Is there a tool to perform hillshade in MapInfo Discover like there is in ArcGIS Desktop?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Discover let's you add hillshading to your DTM quite easily.
From the Surface toolbar click the button Sun-shade Grid and use the Modify Grid Display dialog to set the appropriate settings for your sun-shading.

[image]

We have just released MapInfo Pro 15.2 Advanced which includes the new MapInfo Raster add-on that can work with numerous grid formats.

It does also allow the display of hillshades based on the DTM loaded.

The video [MapInfo Pro Advanced - Image Processing & Display Capabilities](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dvPlCq9rVZA) shows how this will work in MapInfo Pro Advanced.

MapInfo Pro Advanced will be included in MapInfo Discover 2015.2 which is the first 64 bit release of MapInfo Discover.

Answer (score 2):

The PDF entitled [MapInfo Professional and Vertical Mapper: Exploring and Working With Digital Elevation Models](https://katpierce.files.wordpress.com/2007/09/digital_elevation_model.pdf) is from 2007 but says:

> A hillshade drape file was created in Vertical Mapper, by selecting
>   Make 3D Drape File, under the 3D View tab of Grid Manager.

So, if it cannot be done in MapInfo Discover then it may be worth considering Vertical Mapper.